# Image Uploader doesn't exclude white space from the start of the URL & shows invalid image

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader

If you try to upload an image from using the image uploader and if there's some white space at the start of the URL, the upload fails. Removing the space results in successful upload of the image.

[image: image uploader]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ithinkweshouldjustdropallwhitespace,itiscausingnothingbuttrouble.

Comment: Ithinkthatsafantasticidea:P

Comment: wowthatsveryhardtoreadit